# Update subsequent row data if the first line has been updated in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to update the subsequent row if the data at first row has the changes made?

How to construct a proper SQL query for this situation?

```
ID ACTION ORIBALANCE TRANAMOUNT NEWBALANCE
1, Deposit, 1000, 100,1100
2,Deposit,1100,300,1400
3,Deposit,1400,500,1900
4,Withdraw,1900,-300,1600
5,Withdraw,1600,-500,1100
```

If I update the row ID 1, I changed the tranamount from 100 to 500, so the newbalance will be updated to 1500. RowID 2 will update its oribalance from 1100 to 1500. It is cummulative.

Expected result

```
ID ACTION ORIBALANCE TRANAMOUNT NEWBALANCE
1, Deposit, 1000, 500,1600
2,Deposit,1600,300,1900
3,Deposit,1900,500,2400
4,Withdraw,2400,-300,2100
5,Withdraw,2100,-500,1600
```

Comment: You can greatly reduce an amount of work need by dropping `ORIBALANCE` and `NEWBALANCE` from persisted columns. Have them calculated in a view/query.

Comment: The only issue is I have no idea on updating Oribalance for the next row.

Answer (score 1):

You can update it with a workflow kind of

```
-- Start updating row id = 2 for example

declare @id int = 2;
update t set TRANAMOUNT = 500
where id = @id;

-- and update following rows

declare @startb int = (select top(1) ORIBALANCE from t 
where id = @id);
with c as
(
  select id, action, ORIBALANCE, TRANAMOUNT, NEWBALANCE
    , s = @startb + sum(TRANAMOUNT) over(order by id) - TRANAMOUNT
    , n = @startb + sum(TRANAMOUNT) over(order by id)
  from t
  where id >= @id
)
update c
set ORIBALANCE = s, NEWBALANCE = n;
```

But I advise against that because a single row updates triggers blocking the whole table.

Consider creating a view for `ORIBALANCE`, `NEWBALANCE` data.

Answer (score 1):

If I got it correctly, you want to update every row according to the change amount.

```
DECLARE @ChangeAmount INT = 500
DECLARE @ID INT = 1

UPDATE DataTable SET 
    ORIBALANCE = ORIBALANCE + ( CASE WHEN @ID > ID THEN @ChangeAmount ELSE 0 END ),
    NEWBALANCE = NEWBALANCE + @ChangeAmount
WHERE ID >= @ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a cumulative sum and adding in the first value:

```
select ID, ACTION, TRANAMOUNT,
       (sum(TRANAMOUNT) over (order by id) -
        TRANAMOUNT +
        first_value(ORIBALANCE) over (order by id)
       ) as new_oribalance
from t;
```

You can easily put this into an `update`:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*
             (sum(TRANAMOUNT) over (order by id) -
              TRANAMOUNT +
              first_value(ORIBALANCE) over (order by id)
             ) as new_oribalance
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set oribalance = new_oribalance
    where oribalance <> new_oribalance;
```